# how to optimize the query speed with sort and pagination in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here is the basic mysql query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  <table> 
WHERE <conditions>
ORDER BY create_time DESC 
LIMIT X, Y;
```

I'd like to know how to optimize the query speed provided the amount of records in this table is approximately 2 millions. Any advice would be appreciative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Given that the query works, you might want to try CodeReview (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

The one way you can speed up the process is by **creating indexes**.

Create an `index` for `field` which you feel will be

```
 mostly used for look up process.
```

So, which field you think will be mostly used in Where Clause, create an index for that field.

This will speed up the entire process.

**Note:**

If it is the **primary key** for that table, there is **no need to create an index**, since it will be **automatically created**

**Update:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html

Hope this helps

Comment: So, can I understand it this way: If there is no `where` part, this query can provide a quite decent speed with that amount of records?

Comment: If there is no where clause, obviuously there is no need for any lookup process or search process. So, blindly it gets all the records which indeed wil have higher retrieval rate

Comment: There is `order by` clause in my query. I intend to sort by create_time as you can see. The speed will be affected by the sort procedure, won't it?

Comment: Create an index with the search field along with orderby..so it will already keep track of records in that particular order..

Comment: So create `index` for `create_time`?

Answer (score 0):

Its always suggested to use index when ever you are fetching record, which makes you query execution faster and efficient. If you are using `where` keyword its obvious the fetching process will be filtered your conditional data and fetch for you.More on mysql [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Is there any need to create index for items in `order by` clause? say, in this case, create_time?

Comment: It depends, but you can create also.Except primary key , there are certain elements we need to consider .You can prefer non-cluster index.